# What are the differences in the way to get the value of a single environment variable?

Tags: environment-variables

I know the typical way is `echo "$PATH"`, for example. But `echo $PATH` also works. Also, you don't need the `echo` command even, you can just type `$PATH`, and the value of path will be outputted to the screen.

What is the difference in these, and is there any preference for a particular command and why?

Comment: "you can just type $PATH, and the value of path will be outputted to the screen."? Usually it comes in the form of an error message, no? What shell are you using and what's the actual output you get? What do you think that actually does? What if the you had e.g. `var=ls` and then ran just `$var`?

Comment: as for the double quotes, see the mandatory FAQs: [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary) and [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting

Comment: In Bash, also `declare -p PATH`. There is no distinction between printing normal user variables and environment variables.

Answer (score -1):

With quotation marks around the variable, you prevent globbing and word splitting [see shell check](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2086)